# Adding a 50a breaker in main panel to feed 30a rv breaker and plug

Tags: electrical, wiring

I recently purchased a prewired 30a rv subpanel to plug in a travel trailer while sitting at home. The subpanel is complete with a 30a breaker and receptacle. Is it acceptable to run the romex (10-2) to a new 50a breaker in the main panel having the 50a feed the 30a breaker?

Comment: If you're going to go to the trouble of installing an RV power post, I *highly* recommend just using 6/4 and putting in a panel with both 50A service (14-50 receptacle) and 30A (TT-30) service. The parts/wire cost is really not that big of a deal compared to the cost (in either dollars or time) of the installation labor. You'll need a 50A two-pole breaker in the main panel to feed the 6/4 and then the RV subpanel will likely have a 50A two-pole for the 14-50, a 30A single pole for the TT-30, and a 20A single pole for a 5-20 duplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The 10-2 romex has a 30 to 35 amp maximum depending on the insulation. The breaker in the main panel's job is to protect the 10-2 so it has to be a 30 AMP breaker, not the 50 AMP.

If this is going to be a permanent type installation you need to think about running your cable in such a way that it's not a safety hazard or a code violation. You can't have it lying on the ground running from you panel to the trailer.... maybe conduit from the panel to the outside wall and have a receptacle.... then a plug from you subpanel.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I can use a 30a breaker in the main panel to feed another 30a breaker in the rv subpanel? I can also go to an 8-2 romex if needed.

Comment: Yes, two 30's are ok. The 8-2 is good for 40 to 50 AMPS depending on the insulation. You don't need the extra capacity and the larger wire size would cost more than getting a 30 AMP breaker.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wire in 50A for a future, larger RV, then you need to run the cabling with 6/3 UF cable (not NM/Romex, you cannot use Romex because you will be going *outdoors*).

If you were to do that with e 6/3 cable, with the panel you have bought, that would be fine.

However, it's a common case for someone to buy the wrong thing and then go into backflips doing even more wrong things trying to make the wrong thing work.  Don't bother; get the right thing.  If you are mail ordering this stuff, thats a mistake - local electricians must shop somewhere; shop there.

They make RV panels which have all the breakers and sockets necessary to support all of

- a 240V, 50A large RV (with NEMA 14-50 receptacle)
- a 120V, 30A small RV (with TT30 receptacle)
- typically a 120V/20A plain old outlet for hand tools etc.

This works off a 50A breaker because it is presumed you will only be powering one RV at a time.  But you still need 6/3 outdoor cable; 10/3 won't do.

Comment: There are exactly two types of RV plugs in North America, and neither of them are a NEMA 10-anything. The 30A service (120V) RV plug is a TT-30 (line, neutral, ground), and the 50A service (120/240 split phase) RV plug is a 14-50 (line 1, line 2, neutral, ground). 30A on 120/240V is non-standard and will not be found in any modern RV park, and perhaps not in any RV park period.

As a side note, the NEMA 10- receptacles are line 1, line 2, neutral and do *not* have a ground conductor. They are deprecated and cannot and should not be used in any new installations.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. The 10-50 was a typo.  I thought I had seen a 14-30 on an RV stand but I was mistaken.

Comment: Some temporary power outlets provide other types of receptacles, but that's mostly for jobsite use and such